# How to make a cycling variable src attribute for an image in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, variables, src

So I made this code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1> Some Traffic Lights</h1>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <img id="trafficLight" src="TLgre.png" />

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

       //*****Declaring Variables*****//

      var lightSrcs = ['TLgre.png', 'TLyel.png', 'TLred.png'];
      var cycleNumber = 0;
      var Order = 0;

       //*****Number Cycling Function*****//

      function cycle() {
        if (Order === 0) {
          if (cycleNumber == 3) {
            cycleNumber -= 1;
            Order = 1;
          } else {
            cycleNumber += 1;
          }
        } else if (Order === 1) {
          if (cycleNumber <= 0) {
            cycleNumber += 1;
            Order = 0;
          } else {
            cycleNumber -= 1;
          }
        }
        return cycleNumber;
      }
    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('trafficLight').src = lightSrcs[cycle()];">
      Click to cycle lights</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And I don't know why it doesn't work. I did have two guesses, one was that I can't run JavaScript in the onclick event, or that it didn't allow me to use functions from the script tag from this. My other guess was that the src attribute can't be given as a variable, which sounds rather strange, probably why I'm confused. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great, and I'm open to any suggestions on how to improve it, (I know a little AngularJS as well), just one thing, it must have the three images I want in an array. I don't know why either but my teacher said they have to be.

Comment: You can use more angular logic, set up a controller then use angular `ng-src` directive to achieve this. Right now you are mix and matching plain js dom selection and angular. You can easily do this kind of thing in pure angular and you already have the app set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this easier on yourself by using the angular you already have loaded on your page to help you. There's no real point to loading a bigger framework like angular if you're not going to take advantage of it :) .

Anyways, what you're looking for is something like this:  https://plnkr.co/edit/06xChEaDyOEQ89aJktfR?p=preview

You can change your img and button to use angular logic with `ng-click` and `ng-src` like so :

```
<img id="trafficLight" ng-src="{{lightSrcs[currentSelection]}}"></img>

<button type="button" ng-click="cycleLights()" >
```

Then in the controller, you can do something like this :

```
$scope.lightSrcs = ['TLgre.png', 'TLyel.png', 'TLred.png'];
$scope.currentSelection = 0;

$scope.cycleLights = function(){
if($scope.currentSelection === 2) {
  $scope.currentSelection = 0;
} else {
  $scope.currentSelection += 1;
}

};
```

There are even more elegant ways than this one when using an array, but for examples sake, I will just use your logics you have in place. So you have the `ng-click` in on the button which calls a $scope function in your controller that is wrapped over them. You can then rotate the count in that function. Then you use `ng-src` on the img to have angular properly evaluate the image location, using the array and index you are rotating.

Comment: Wow, thanks dude, not gonna lie, I didn't know ng-src even existed, probably should have thought about something like that.

Comment: @AzrielBowles no problem, glad I could help. Angular has a ton too it, it can take a bit to learn, but it has a ton of tools in place to handle quite a bit of problems! If this solution works for you please mark is as correct so the question is no longer open.